# passing parameters to Node.js async waterfall

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, node-async

I need to pass some parameters to the initial function of [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) [`waterfall()`](https://github.com/caolan/async#waterfalltasks-callback). The proposed method  https://github.com/caolan/async/issues/14 does not work for me as I need to pass it the response from an ExpressJS function

```
exports.categories = (req, res) ->
    async.waterfall [           
       (callback) ->
         # need req here...
```

Comment: "*need req here*." You should already [have it in scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Closures#Practical_closures) there.

Comment: I was using that as an example but yes you are correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
async.waterfall [
  ( (req, callback) ->

  ).bind(null, req)
]
```

Answer (score 4):

See [async.apply()](https://github.com/caolan/async#apply).

```
async.waterfall([
  async.apply(function(req, callback) {}, req);
]);
```

Comment: This answer is also one of the way to achieve it. async.apply(fnName, req);
Thanks